# Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to call a function from external contract (Exchange) which was created from another contract (Factory)

For that, I am passing the contract address to create an instance.

I am getting following error if I call the addLiquidity function:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
      at Exchange.getReserve (src/contracts/Exchange.sol:72)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
      at EthModule._estimateGasAction (/Users/ag/Documents/eth_swap/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:421:9)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (/Users/ag/Documents/eth_swap/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:126:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/Users/ag/Documents/eth_swap/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:103:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (/Users/ag/Documents/eth_swap/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:188:20)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (/Users/ag/Documents/eth_swap/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:167:17)
```

I am testing using the local environment from hardhat.

```js
addLiquidity = async (tokenAmount: string, ethAmount: string) => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  const accounts = await this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts();
  try {
    const dexAddress = await this.state.factory.methods
      .getExchange(this.state.tokenAddress.toString())
      .call();

    if (dexAddress.startsWith('0x00')) {
      console.log('IN');
      await this.state.factory.methods
        .createExchange(this.state.tokenAddress)
        .send({ from: this.state.account });
      const dexAddress = await this.state.factory.methods
        .getExchange(this.state.tokenAddress)
        .call();
      this.setState({ exchangeAddress: dexAddress });
    } else {
      console.log('IN2');
      const dexAddress = await this.state.factory.methods
        .getExchange(this.state.tokenAddress)
        .call();
      this.setState({ exchangeAddress: dexAddress });
    }
    const exchange = new this.state.web3.eth.Contract(
      Exchange.abi as AbiItem[],
      this.state.exchangeAddress
    );


    await this.state.token.methods
      .approve(this.state.exchangeAddress, tokenAmount)
      .send({
        from: accounts[0],
      });

    await exchange.methods.addLiquidity(tokenAmount).send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: ethAmount,
    }).on('receipt', (hash: any) => {
      console.log('LP');
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    })
    .on('error', (error: any, receipt: any) => {
      // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
      console.log(error);
      if (error.code === 4001) {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    return;
  }
};
```